# Impdp overwrite source data

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm pretty new in Oracle and I need some help.
I wanna dump some tables from STAT user to ALLSTAT.

STAT got imp_full_database privelege, ALLSTAT got exp_full_database one, no dba privileges.

I'm testing impdp on my localhost, so NETWORK LINK was created like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK transport CONNECT TO STAT IDENTIFIED BY STATPASS USING '127.0.0.1:1521/XE';
```

Than i try in cmd:

```
impdp ALLSTAT/ALLSTATPASS@XE NETWORK_LINK=transport TABLES=STAT.LOGS CONTENT=ALL TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE;
```

I got no error messages, but after this script, i got empty LOGS table on STAT user.

In my opinion, during impdp, it trying to import data into table not ALLSTAT.LOGS but STAT.LOGS which are exported.

I can see, edit, drop STAT.* tables even if i logged as ALLSTAT user.

Could you tell me, which way should i go to get ALLSTAT own table LOGS with data from STAT.LOGS?

P.S. Sorry for my English :(

Comment: doesn't look like you have exported the data from STAT.
you need to expdp STAT data
then impdp and perform a remap_schema function into ALLSTAT

i've assumed you are using Oracle 11g

Comment: @davegreen100
If i'm not mistaking, using NETWORK_LINK parameter doesn't require expdp at all.

I tried use REMAP_SCHEMA=ALLSTAT:STAT in impdp statement but it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Founded a solution.

```
impdp ALLSTAT/ALLSTATPASS@XE NETWORK_LINK=transport TABLES=STAT.LOGS CONTENT=ALL TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE REMAP_SCHEMA=STAT:ALLSTAT;
```

REMAP_SCHEMA=STAT:ALLSTAT is required,

thx to @davegreen100

Answer (score 0):

`impdp` command with `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE` works for me.